# How to generate map file using Windriver Workbench

Tags: vxworks, wind-river-workbench

I am using Windriver workbench for Vxworks project but i am not able to find the option to generate map file. Can anybody help with this ??? In other eclipse IDE's(Sourcery Code bench) it was wasy to mention -m flag in linker/miscellaneous section but in Windriver workbench there is option like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer myself. In workbench it is bit different in the way we specify the flags compare to other eclipse IDE. Right Click on Project>>Properties>>BuildProperties>>Tools>>select linker build tool
specify the flags as -m > filename.map

Thats it